# Signature Pad not Working in window phonw 8.1 RT, Xamarin form(PCL)

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, xamarin.forms, signaturepad

We are facing an issue on creating signature pad on windows Phone 8.1 RT ( Not window phone Silverlight) Using Xamarin Form (Portable class library), can you please recommend which library or component to go ahead with, can you please respond as soon as possible.